# Box2d Why isn't the physics collision perfect?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, collision-detection, physics

I ran some test with java and box2d and i found out through debugging that the collision has an error of 0.015 meters and that small error ruins everything. I want to ask if this is normal because i didn't find anything about this problem anywhere. To be more precise i defined terrain made of two blocks with a fixed gap between them and a character exactly as wide as that gap. Moving the character between those two blocks is impossible. I get some really buggy movements, like the character enters through the first block and gets stuck in the corner of it. After this I printed out to the console the positions and i have seen that when I try to collide two blocks there is the following problem: Static body at position 0(for x in meters) and 4(for y in meters) and dynamic body which is thrown at the block at position -1(for x in meters) and 4(for y in meters) collides with the static body at -0.01 and 4 which should actually be 0 and 4. This messes everything when you try to go through a fixed gap... Is there any way to solve this? I used only box2d coordinates so no pixel conversion needed(this was debug mode).

Comment: No need for any additional information. The answer I was given is true. The physics isn't perfect, you can still go through the gap if you move the character yourself and you block rotation, so your character isn't shifted right or left. That was one of the problems that cause the gap problem, the other one is the collision which can be made of higher quality through number of iterations which i modified from 8  to 900. That solved my problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, this is expected behavior. If you read the Box2D manual, it mentions that shapes should be around 1 unit in size for best results. I recommend scaling up the physics world to make your player about that size.

Comment: I scaled the physics up to 1:32 (meters:pixels). It didn't solve anything. I think that box2d is just buggy. I stated that I printed the coordinates to console and when the objects collided the coordinates of their edges didn't have same coordinates.

Comment: Please read the section at the end of the manual titled "Limitations": http://www.box2d.org/manual.html See also the second question on this page: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/gotchas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This imprecision is likely caused because box2d does all calculations in discrete steps, so in each step, a body will move a certain distance all at once, as opposed to continuously. Since your character is exactly the width of the gap, it's highly unlikely it will ever be at a point where it fits exactly between that gap. A good resource to look into how exactly box2d handles collisions can be found [here](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy) at iforce2d.net. As is shown in that tutorial, collisions are never exact for normal bodies, during a collision, two bodies will instead slightly overlap, which may be what's causing your buggy movement since the gap is *exactly* the width of the character trying to enter it.

[image]

Now, to solve this, you could try making your character a bullet. Collisions are much more accurate for bullet bodies, and this may be able to help with your issue. Alternatively, you could increase the number of iterations during each world step for the solver, which will make everything more precise.

```
//Increase velocityIterations and positionIterations for increased precision
//Decreasing the timeStep could also help, but that would slow down everything as well
b2World.step(timeStep, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
```

However, it's likely you'll have to resort to either very slightly widening the gap, or very slightly decreasing the width of your character, as getting something *that* exact with a physics engine that works in discrete steps doesn't seem like it will ever work out 100% of the time.